# Understanding chef attributes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm a chef newbie and trying to wrap my head around the difference between

```
default[:foo] = 'something'
```

and

```
node[:foo]
```

and

```
node.default[:foo] = 'nothing'
```

I understand that there is an attribute precedence for attributes in the chef docs but I still want to validate if my understanding is correct.

**My understanding**

- `default[:foo] = 'something'` this is lowest precedence and sets `foo`
- `node[:foo]` this is not setting anything, just getting value of foo, typical use case is for conditional statements
- `node.default[:foo] = 'nothing'` overrides `default[:foo]`

I guess the point I want to prove here is `node[:foo]` is for only getting and not setting, and also true for `default[:foo]` and `node.default[:foo]` they are only for setter attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chef conventions are changing from time to time.
if you are using latest chef version, you should use `node.default` and not the old ways.

read [attribute precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) for more information

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to think about node attributes is just as variables.

- `node.default[:foo] = 'something'`  # assigns the attribute/variable
- `node.default[:foo]`  # Accesses the contents of the attribute/variable

It gets more complicated with the different levels of precedence, but thats the gist.

`default[:foo] = 'something'` and  `node.default[:foo] = 'something'` are functionally the same thing.  You can use default without node at the front in Attributes files, but not in recipes.  Its just a shortcut.

Chef loads the attributes files first, so if you have set default[:foo] there and then set node.default[:foo] in a recipe the value will be overwritten.